# WordPress login page redirecting to "page not found"

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

> Hi,  I am currently working on a Wordpress site and suddenly I got
>   this error message " page not found" , I tried to login into pw-admin
>   to check the permalinks values but I couldnot login into admin or
>   front end .
>
> **Could you please help me ?**

Comment: Do you have access to the database?

Comment: Yes I have access on it

Comment: Ok.  That's good.  What happens when you go to:  yoursite.com?  How about yoursite.com/wp-admin?

Comment: If they both show 404s then you probably need to go into the database and make sure the base site urls are set correctly.

Comment: Yes , It's correct and this is permalinks value /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you accidentally miss-set the 'siteurl' and/or 'home' values for your installation.  If that is true, you can reset them through the database.  If you named your tables according to the default, the `wp_options` table is where you should look.  Search for `siteurl` and `home` in the `option_name` column and replace them with the correct value for the site.

In most cases they should both be `https://example.com/`.

**Edit**
Since this answer has been accepted as correct, I will add the comment that I think actually helped the questioner to the answer.

Every link generated by the system is adding /ar/home-2-2/ to the url. You've got some weird redirects going on. It probably has to do with whatever plugin you're using to get multiple language versions of the site going. Try disabling that plugin (you can just rename the folder of the plugin, if you have access to filesystem) and see if returns to normal.

Comment: It's correct and I was working well but suddenly this problem happened but i donot remember if I changed the permalinks values :

Comment: try resetting permalinks to a default value:  /%postname%/

Comment: I did but nothing please check the website url   http://m.elarabygroup.com:8088/elarabyonline/

Comment: every link generated by the system is acting like /ar/home-2-2/ is the homepage.  You've got some weird redirects going on.  It probably has to do with whatever plugin you're using to get multiple language versions of the site going.  Try disabling that plugin (you can just rename the folder of the plugin, if you have access to filesystem) and see if returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

if your not able to access frontend and backend.Please check your site url in database